# Passing 2D array in C

Tags: arrays, pointers

I want to display the elements of a 2D array by passing a pointer to a function. I successfully did it for 1D array.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void displaymat(int *a);

int main()
{
  int a[3]={0,1,2};
  int t[3][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

  displaymat(a);

  return 0;
}

void displaymat(int *a)
{
  int i;

  for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    printf("%d\n",a[i]);/*works for single dimensional array*/
}
```

But when I use `displaymat(t)`, it gives me an error saying incompatible pointer type.
However `displaymat(&t[0][0])` seems to work. Why this apparent difference in passing pointer between 1D and 2D arrays?

Comment: `int t[3][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};` is a 1-D array. The value of t[1][2] is dependent on whether data is stored in row-major or column-major order. Are you sure this is what you intended to do?

Comment: @Iceardor-My bad, with proper initialization of the 2D array, displaymat(t) seems to work. What exactly is int t[3][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; then and why displaymat(t) gives me an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`t` is of type `int**`, which is a pointer to an array of int pointers.

`a` is of type `int*`

`&t[0][0]` is of type `int*`.

You should be able to call `displaymat(t[0])`,  `displaymat(t[1])`, and `displaymat(t[2])`